# TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar

I am just adding the events to calendar.

============This is my Code============

```
events: function (start, end , callback) {
            var events = [];
            calEvents=Events.find();
            calEvents.forEach(function(evt){
                events.push({
                    id:evt._id,
                    title:evt.title,
                    start:evt.date,
                });
            });
            console.log(events);
            callback(events);
        },
```

But in console, I am getting this Error And None of events showing on calendar.

**TypeError: callback is not a function**

Comment: In your last line you're trying to do `callback(events)`, thus calling `callback` as a function. Apparently, whatever you're putting into the `callback` variable is not a function reference. It would help to see what input you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [the docs for FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/), you can see that it's expecting a third argument before the callback: `timezone`.

```
function( start, end, timezone, callback ) { }
```

Therefore right now, your code is using the timezone (which you named `callback`) as a function, and it doesn't like that very much. Just add `timezone` in your code as shown above, and your callback should work.

Comment: Thanks for the replay Sir.Now it's Working.

Comment: But my events list is not updating by adding new event.
Can you help me in this?

Comment: You'll have to use `autorun` for reactivity to occur. [Here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Tracker-autorun)'s a documentation page to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for this, but
I am unable to use it.
Can you please explain it little bit.