# Fullcalendar React component throwing TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying to include a Fullcalendar component into my React app. I've followed the guidelines shown in [the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react) to get this code

```js
import React from "react";
import { Box } from "./general"
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";

function CalendarBox() {
    return (
        <Box title="Calendar">
            <FullCalendar 
                plugins={[ dayGridPlugin ]}
                initialView="dayGridMonth"/>
        </Box>
    )
}
export default CalendarBox
```

But when I try to render it, I get

> Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

> The above error occurred in the  component:
> in CalendarDataProvider (created by FullCalendar)
> in FullCalendar (created by CalendarBox)

I tried with the exact code from the docs as well

```js
import React from 'react'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react' // must go before plugins
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid' // a plugin!

export default class DemoApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FullCalendar
        plugins={[ dayGridPlugin ]}
        initialView="dayGridMonth"
      />
    )
  }
}
```

and tried in [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/beautiful-buck-cu11p) where it works perfectly, but in my project I still get
[image: TypeError: callback is not a function]

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I've already checked some other SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993913/uncaught-typeerror-callback-is-not-a-function-fullcalendar), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044665/typeerror-callback-is-not-a-function), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099128/uncaught-typeerror-callback-is-not-a-function), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65165692/uncaught-typeerror-callback-is-not-a-function-setting-the-events-in-fullca). But none of them use the react component or the problem arises when adding events

Comment: Your code is somewhat different from the documentation in a couple of places. Have you tried implementing it exactly as shown in the example? Not being a React expert I don't know what the implications of the differences would be exactly, but it seems like a good idea to change the code to match the example, as a way of ruling that in or out as an issue.

Comment: @ADyson yes, I tried doing that. I erased my CalendarBox and replaced it by DemoApp copied from the documentation but the error still arises

Comment: Strange. Can you make a runnable demo which reproduces the error, using codesandbox (similar to the demo provided in the fullCalendar/React documentation?)

Comment: Good idea, I've run a demo with the documentation code here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/beautiful-buck-cu11p and it works perfectly there, I can't reproduce the error...

Comment: Strange. You need to do a very detailed comparison between that and your environment then. Perhaps strip your environment back to the bare essentials required for React and fullCalendar to run with the demo code, and then build it back up again until it breaks.

Comment: Yes, it seems it has something to do with my environment just as you said, I'll try to build it up it's a pretty complex application already, so this will take time...